# Rails Pictures sort date

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, model, controller, exif

In Exifr for rails (im using this fork https://github.com/picuous/exifr ) how do i sort out the pictures according to date
this is how to get the date

```
EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').date_time           # => Fri Feb 09 16:48:54 +0100 2007
```

if im too vague let me know how to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the pictures as a list just use [Ruby's normal `sort` function](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort) (or sort!, if you want it in-place), so:

```
images.sort! { |img1, img2| img1.date_time <=> img2.date_time }
```